# Export grease pencil blender to Unity

Tags: export, unity, grease-pencil

Currently, I am working on a student project with the grease pencil blender.

I'm trying to export the GP to create an interactive scene on Unity. But I can't find any way to export the GP to Unity because it looks like Blender.
I tried to convince the GP to mesh and extrude, but it doesn't look like what I want and can't find anything on exporting from GP to Unity.

I have try this :

1. Convert To Path > Convert To Polygons
2. Convert To Path > Extrude
3. Convert To Polygons Cuves > Convert To Mesh

Anyone know if there is something to switch Gp to Unity (or some other rendering engine) without losing the "graphics channel" of Gp ?

Comment: this thread could help you: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/ji7ok9/blender_grease_pencil/ I haven't had time to try it out yet, but it seems a proper way. There is also this:
https://github.com/PierreMervaillie/GreasePencilToUnity